# Creating a TypeScript type from a deep key of an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, jsonschema

I have the following object:

```js
const schemas = {
  POST: {
    $schema: 'https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema#',
    $id: 'https://api.netbizup.com/v1/health/schema.json',
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      body: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          greeting: {
            type: 'boolean',
          },
        },
        additionalProperties: false,
      },
    },
    required: ['body'],
  } as const,
  PUT: {
    $schema: 'https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema#',
    $id: 'https://api.netbizup.com/v1/health/schema.json',
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      body: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          modified: {
            type: 'string',
          },
        },
        required: ['modified'],
        additionalProperties: false,
      },
    },
    required: ['body'],
  } as const,
};
```

I'm trying to create a type that would extract the `body` property type from the above object, so if:

`type MyType = { body: TWhatGoesHere }`

...then `TWhatGoesHere` would be equal to:

`{ greeting?: boolean } | { modified: string }`

I am using `FromSchema` from the `json-schema-to-ts` package to infer the `body` type from the `const` object above, but I'm unable to "automatically" create this type.

Comment: You have trailing commas at "required: ['body'],", maybe this is stopping the parser?

Comment: The parser is working very well. I'm just unable to create a utility type that would extract the above automatically instead of me doing it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a utility type; it's as simple as (very long) bracket notation:

```
type SchemaBodies = (typeof schemas)[keyof typeof schemas]["properties"]["body"]["properties"];
```

The important part is `keyof typeof schemas`, which results in a union of all the values.

P. S. It might help to understand it if you gradually add each path in the bracket notation :)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-eiiC49EAIgtHtWZ9PZ-6gxv58vZYgN-7QA)

Comment: Thank you very much! The reason I was talking about a utility type is that I wanted to be able to "apply" this to each input schema I have in the app -- there are a lot. It's not like I can make the type a "function". No?

Comment: You can make it a generic (`SchemaBodies<S> = S[keyof S]...`) and use `SchemaBodies<typeof schemas>`

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried: `type BodySchema<S> = S[keyof S]['properties']['body'];` but I'm getting this error: `TS2536: Type '"properties"' cannot be used to index type 'S[keyof S]'.`

Comment: I forgot the generic constraint `S extends { [key: string]: { properties: { body: { properties: unknown; } } } }`

Comment: By the way, the issue here remains that if PUT and POST above have different attributes/properties (which is the case) the union does not work :-(