# TypeScript Intersection (not Union) Type from JSON Schema

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, jsonschema, typescript-generics

I'm following up on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71382164/creating-a-typescript-type-from-a-deep-key-of-an-object):

I have the following schema:

```js
const schemas = {
  POST: {
    $schema: 'https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema#',
    $id: 'https://api.netbizup.com/v1/health/schema.json',
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      body: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          greeting: {
            type: 'string',
          },
        },
        additionalProperties: false,
      },
    },
    required: ['body'],
  } as const,
  PUT: {
    $schema: 'https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema#',
    $id: 'https://api.netbizup.com/v1/health/schema.json',
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      body: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          modified: {
            type: 'boolean',
          },
        },
        required: ['modified'],
        additionalProperties: false,
      },
    },
    required: ['body'],
  } as const,
};
```

I am using `FromSchema` from the `json-schema-to-ts` package to infer the type of each `body` attribute the `const` object above.

What I need to achieve is an intersection type of `POST` and `PUT` bodies. The answer provided in the previous question was perfect to create a TypeScript `Union`. The problem is of course that when I try to access members of `body` I get an error since not all attributes will always exist on each `body`.

I was even wondering if TypeScript allows us to verify that if we access one attribute from a "chosen" `body` object, then it won't allow us to access the other.

I created a [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&module=6&pretty=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgMShEBlAxgCwKYgCGcAvnAGZohwDkAVgM4QB2AtA7gYazBDwzQDcAWABQYrCwbwO+IgzgBeRGLhwACgHkMAFQBcK0WrUASWVwM0cMGGAZ6A9A8Yt2nIgDpoAcwcATKEJyGAcAJgAGAEYATlZw6IdzIgBiGgAaVWMTYD9La1t7J0IwYA9mPBgAI2AALwBXMA9JEAcAN0iHfEIAGxgcRPdCDxdmdMy1GABPMDxLCEq6PCwYMaNjMDQZ2GA8e0NjY0qIP0mDBHGDuCmZuYWllYy1y7gNiC2YHb3zp+e4byg8BVgMxvGcLr8rtNZrRpFBgd5VhC1CRHhCUeDjIQ-H5gB8WD11Js8NtdgZyD0GHhUZd0T9aQcAQBHOrAAG5OAAbRoRxONAAutSyIQFJJmNJqeoAKr6fZZJKEPI2OyOZxMNjyrxQXwBIIhCIxOIJeWpammHKKgoq4qlcpVWoNJroNodLq9foakaI4zXaE0eaLZZetSvd6fME-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-ICHwgpY4F4N03QQAAhK+CU7r18AVhAfTEgAaj0OTqANMBDRVDljZFJwMetEgbi8p5nSNF04Vd0ZIG22a5gYMBQHUeDxTuQA) to illustrate my question.

**ANNEX**

Playground where the answer partially works: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&module=6&pretty=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgMShEBlAxgCwKYgCGcAvnAGZohwDkAVgM4QB2AtA7gYazBDwzQDcAWABQoSLERwAggAUAkgHFCMPAHdCATzloAHloCiANzzMYANQBMAdWAwcAKRsAVGQFcH0YAC88UUgoqWkJ1BlYAG0IQACMAE0IhMTEsFgZ4DnwiBjgAXkQxODg5AHkMFwAuAtEiooASTK4qmhwYGDAGCoB6LsYWdk4iADpoAHMuuKhCchguqwAGAEYATlZ55a7GogBiGgAaQtq64Djm1vbOnsIwYCHmPBgY33cwIdSQLuNFrvxCCIdNoNCEM+sx9ocijAtGA8M0IDE6HgsDBwTVamA0DDYMA8J1qrVajEIHEtFUEBCCXAoTC4QikSiDmjKXAMRAsTAcXjyUzmXBRlA8A9gMxRmSKbyqdDYbR0lBhaNURKiiRGRKVeLaoQ4nF7MAWH9dGz-BzcVVyH8GHhVZT1TzbQSBQBHdzAAWnOAAbRoRJJNAAutayIQcqlmOlrXIAKqVfFHLaEM5tDrdXpMNjxkZQcaTaazBYrNYbeO7a31E6Ji4p663e6PZ6vd6fb6-f44QFZYGgxW1anSmjwxHI7tFVnszlinlFH2k2PM3u0wcMjUjzHG8ez3kgYnAcg493cpU9qXNIkQCJ4Qhg0u8+0368OvDO114d1erc63cv-33zXa3X6iJDTHU0KAtK0NVvZVrydF03SqL1p2-Q4gxDNIYEZEgRFEMRezgBRmDATxsA7ABpPAtDyWglEMFwaDgAAfWhSnKOjGJoKNaIYpiZBcABhAAJVjaAAEUMAAZGjDCSbDRFw-DCJgYiuByfJuQASA9ABrci4GFPCCKIoEyK0P0yRZVdsRApBpyqdxmE05gIHUZhAkwsQ3Jkno4BsHBVBoHJ1DQEU4HUewcDgFwlKIOA8D0NRmB1YL5MMjsckIIlTAAfjELyFCpHBhU0-LgByEq4GIGJ3FGXSXJcKVsDlMB4HUfABTge50hfcyjVgCjCCwLBcRyFgarUKBzUGrpcIHelJRhHIBQYdx-lKlz-DQKAGCGHCpTgAAhYktCiwgAB5IqBGK4rMOIciQLTyKqWV5VM6RRzXKy4BsuA7IcpyXLIAGAD5KPOjt7q0CByAi46-S9N7LIEWHvUO-0sJyro4HOZMenSfrNIgUxxoiJy3nQLpnVxDk0i6ABWGnFisAB2eZ5gAFh+JyeD4GApjDchoBAVg7L1Nhey5ngXnPHgpWSUQvIgcKiQouIWBoeAVeKhgdphOBI2YEWXAgfCxstZERZOyNgdyQ4AApI0u+KbvK5gKMyuAbc0qpIwASjyYHjAgE44Cqe5Cd92LHZyG2PaqYVyH8PDfdyf3A7iX23bykO8EJ7W8DgMTgxgEpyDOq3Dj1g2jfMfxTap5gzod660pduA3ZtpPgZcYP2uz-xgYjpv3Y79244TgAldO4DH7vQ-8WWvMi1mhnmABqXPincBgcAbgeEubrQPQDOALCtz0hnPlw9mPv00bljHF6GRY19k3aK5YQ2XElvAzqvsTKIL9IxdS5XwAHKUQ9C4P0jc96elnlAKBbsebuDzmaMCZc0RILzrvJ2YC3aH27nITe2837MA-l-E6hg9BYAiO4OI39L750BoDX+gNZa4V4iwQmMAZARAiD-Ke0CnZjwvCrZgEQtAyCgFMLQJ0fqOWcqfQ+p8u7YJyB6UeARkCunDHAc+QwNFT0pgguAHDmBcJ4Xw4ROiPR6LHlfVA6BjonS0ZtGAgM-TAyqGPW+uEHEgAscdBgFtT6mPMbwi2+t34QE-mAc8wTAYemYO4WI-gb5sN2i4A6JJKLWUOlUPxASgRBKyUdIEJ1eyQzgPGBgTDBCkFlqGdILIIDpBKVUTJh0cmfTydIfkgoOQimaPxPAvCIAAEI6IAywo0+Al4IAOH8BYP4Jw5AtJgG0iKJSulfSQFMlIaEWSeA2R07JqlukkjMu+Hce4qiYNcj43aJT+KXjiOeKAZ0SnHVPjbMQale7mCqCUEA9gTryGUKoDQ2hDQGBMGYSwtgwrODcJ4HA3g-BQCvsjX0wMABk1Q1JqS+ic0pHZBG3TIG7ApvDAknU+WU4lXzPFVJ5vKLCalbTDwDicW+MzzlaGeQlN5lEzoCtef4OlpL8hyL+oDH5og1K+UFf4KoTyXlvJFWq8Vh0vliGHkgAUMB3BQH+g0g5iqxUBHyNOUV6qqURBpRKrg5SpSVOqUw2V5UGBaGYFgd2-yYB6sOI0s8eAhjE1GDbCpUN-VDGnN7LCJBvZAA

Comment: It seems as if FromSchema cannot handle a union of the schemas. You can get around this by turning the union into a tuple, converting each schema in the tuple with FromSchema, then converting it back to a union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems as if FromSchema cannot handle a union of the schemas. You can get around this by turning the union into a tuple, converting each schema in the tuple with FromSchema, then converting it back to a union.

For this we will first need the excellent holy grail of a post in
[How to transform union type to tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type)

I've renamed `TuplifyUnion` to `UnionToTuple` here.

Let us then write a type that converts a union of schemas we wish to transform.

We need to convert this union to a tuple, then convert each of the schemas separately, and finally turn the resulting tuple back into a union.

```
type FromAllSchemas<U> = ConvertAll<UnionToTuple<U>>[number];
```

This is done with `UnionToTuple` and `[number]`.

Now let's write `ConvertAll`.

```
type ConvertAll<T, R extends ReadonlyArray<unknown> = []> =
    T extends [infer First, ...infer Rest]
        ? ConvertAll<Rest, [...R, FromSchema<First>]>
        : R;
```

First we infer the first element and the rest as a tuple.

We then convert the first element to a type with FromSchema, and put it in the results. Then we "call" `ConvertAll` again, this time with the rest of the elements and new result.

Finally, if we couldn't infer the first element that means T is empty, so we just return the result R.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&module=6&pretty=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgMShEBlAxgCwKYgCGcAvnAGZohwDkAVgM4QB2AtA7gYazBDwzQDcAWABQYrCwbwO+IgzgBeRGLhwACgHkMAFQBcK0WrUASWVwM0cMGGAZ6A9A8Yt2nIgDpoAcwcATKEJyGAcAJgAGAEYATlZw6IdzIgBiGgAaVWMTYD9La1t7J0IwYA9mPBgAI2AALwBXMA9JEAcAN0iHfEIAGxgcRPdCDxdmdMy1GABPMDxLCEq6PCwYMaNjMDQZ2GA8e0NjY0qIP0mDBHGDuCmZuYWllYy1y7gNiC2YHb3zp+e4byg8BVgMxvGcLr8rtNZrRpFBgd5VhC1CRHhCUeDjIQ-H5gB8WD11Js8NtdgZyD0GHhUZd0T9aQcAQBHOrAAG5OAAbRoRxONAAutSyIQFJJmNJqeoAKr6fZZJKEPI2OyOZxMNjyrxQXwBIIhCIxOIJeWpammHKKgoq4qlcpVWoNJroNodLq9foakaI4zXaE0eaLZZetSvd6fME-NQ806y54+24Bh4Y4NEklfJPGEDHYDkHbs75I71QyxHCDdPCEUam3706tVhl4ZmsvDsrmZnE55v8uuY7G44D47qEt7Ej6kigUqkYmvIqtMllsgxcqNdzJCkVSGCPEgicSiH1wACSzDAdRg2DkhAA0nhJkpaABxACiOhocAAPrQtLpXx+aFKX++n4AII6AAwgAEj+tAACKPgAMs+j5CGIYj7keJ5noMCjKN8ACQHIANY3nAwKHsep7nlw16THyZwvCmo5fHAUYGHUzAEcwEAAO7MKQpA7tuKGiE4cAAOo4IQKwKFxaAgnAXG4jgcA6JRRBwHgAAeMB4MwOJyehFFYXAhBHK0eAAPxiCJB5XDgwIEbZwAKE5xnMXU3gkbxOhQtgcJgPAXH4ACcDlNIzb0cOsC3oQWBYLsCgsJ52lQOScUOPu-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-D41j4aVg3R1H4I9N1bc1zWPc1CfuoEWB3RgEBbo3RR6JxXgoWO5Z8bMG6JMICUBAiTEapNTiPE66Vzrl7E+q8Y5QBQKycUcAG4eAIYnV6m84CAOYMA0B4CYEkI5GQ2OzdUDoAao1ZAxCYBzT5AtAwsc277g4SABhDUGDMzrrQ+hYDmZUwHhAIeYAyzSLmmvOoIBKgbxEVVHQtUTh3jGnVAwYiJFYUaoY+qgxGo+jWnAeUDBv6CFIEJUU0gXgQGkNYgwBi6rGOYqYoa-xAQfBBJYcCeAwEQAAISvlmjuDx8AKwQD6MSauPQcjqG8TAXxylrGBPGkgRJEgNwvFPPk-xRicJBJOHRNs2ZcwGCPnxQSoggA)

Comment: I'm going to try all this now and mark your answer; but irrespective of the results, thanks a bunch for being so patient and comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks again. If you may please take a look at this playground: (I added the URL to the annex of the question since I cannot paste it here) you'll see that even though it works directly, I cannot pass the exact same type as a generic to a function -- it then gives the body type as unknown.

Comment: Hi you can make it a link like [this](https://example.com) and use https://tsplay.dev to shorten links :)

Comment: @Sammy Ok to answer your question, change the line where you call `bodyHandler`. It should only be `bodyHandler<typeof schemas>` because you convert the schema inside `BodyHandler` already!

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's just that the problem prevails -- I'm talking now about the original problem that you resolved: https://tsplay.dev/W48R7W

Comment: Oh if you're going to use it like that... You could make an assertion type guard or instead of a union of bodies merge them all... but that does not seem like the best. What is the use case here?

Comment: Yeah, the use case is that the middleware might receive HTTP requests as PUT or POST (amongst others), each having its own body format.

Comment: You might want to try type guards first if there aren't too many body types.